# Some of the Terminal commands do not work on Node.Js

Tags: node.js, windows-terminal

So, I have to use Node.JS for a learning project, however, I couldn't make it functional.

First I tried installing the recommended version, which first try didn't work.
I could only open this version when I tried opening it trough the source code.

Later, I tried the most recent version. It was installed apparently flawlessly, And I could open it directly through the Node.JS terminal and the Windows CMD (which, except for Node, is working perfectly). But, I couldn't make some really importants commands work such as "cd", "ls", etc:

[Failed Commands on Node Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKxll.png)

[Failed Commands on Windows CMD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hq5ni.png)

JavaScript commands such as functions, if statements, booleans, etc are working fine:

[JS Commands](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwUj8.png)

What can I do to fix the problem and use all of the terminal features?

Thanks you for your time, and I am sorry for poor vocabulary, english is my second language.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you're trying to execute **cmd** commands while you're in **node** command environment (or in other words, you're in the [node CLI](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html)).

When you issue the command `node` without any parameters you're actually getting migrated to the **node cli**. Furthermore, when you're already there, the context changes and you're actually writing javascript at this point, hence the errors you get. So, you're no executing the command `cd` but you're trying to reference a variable named `cd` which is not defined, thus => `ReferenceError: cd is not defined`.

Open a **cmd** window and type `node -v` and you'll see it works.